# Bootstrap 3.2.0 with Simple_form checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

I have a form

```
 = simple_form_for([:admin, @user]) do |f|
  = f.input :email
  = f.association :roles, as: :select
  - if @user.has_role? :moderator
    = f.input :question, as: :boolean
    = f.input :answer, as: :boolean
    = f.input :comment, as: :boolean
  = f.submit 'Update'
```

With bootstrap 3.1 checkboxes works as expected, but with 3.2 they are not shown, just only label shown. 
Html code of form:

```
<label class="checkbox"><input checked="checked" class="boolean optional" id="user_question" name="user[question]" type="checkbox" value="1"></label>
```

What it can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add .form-inline to form.